# How to retrieve Data from html page using jsp keywords?

Tags: html, jsp, getparameter

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    ques1 = (String)request.getParameter("ques%><%=i%><%");
    out.println(ques1);
}
```

I just want to get the parameters from the HTML page for ques1, ques2, ques3 and so on. But it's giving unterminated String literal.

My HTML input:

```
Enter Question  No. <%=i%> :: <input name="ques<%=i%>"  required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    ques1 = (String)request.getParameter("ques" + i);
    out.println(ques1);
}
```